# Ubuntu 18.04 - how to set up a Python virtual environment for Python 3.7.x or 3.8.x?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Can somebody please provided recommended commands for Ubuntu 18.04 to configure a Python virtual environment that has Python 3.7.x or 3.8.x?

Of course I'm aware that upgrading the general Ubuntu 18.04 Python install past 3.6.9 (the current Ubuntu 18.04 Python version if all updates have been done) could have disastrous consequences for many other OS functionalities so of course this is not something I'd like to try.

If you're wondering, I need access to some of the `asyncio` functionality for a WebSockets application that has been introduced after Python 3.6.9.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544) hints at how to do it, but it's very old and does not provide complete instructions.  Also I'm unclear on `venv` vs `virtualenv`.

Comment: Is that for development or just run some specific script in that version? Because for the latter you could consider using a Docker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'd rather not use Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this site](https://itnext.io/virtualenv-with-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu-18-04-goran-aviani-d7b712d906d5) because it has good instructions on setting up virtualenv on Ubuntu 18.04.

In the .bashrc I had to enter:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```